# Matching NSPredicate With String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

I have this predicate which works somewhat well.

`NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code contains[cd] %@", predicateFilter];`

So if `predicateFilter` is 112, this finds all `code` that have `112` in it.  I want it to find all code that BEGIN with `112` instead.

Edit:

I have this predicate, how can I make it so its codes that are between code that begins with predicateFilterStart and code that begins with PredicateFilterEnd?

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                      [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [self.predicateFilterStart floatValue]]],
                      [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [self.predicateFilterEnd floatValue]]],
                      nil]];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code beginswith[cd] %@", predicateFilter];
```

[Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't exactly what I was looking for.  I want to find code that fits between code that stars with `predicateFilter` (such as 20) and `predicateFilterEnd` (such as 30).  So code between codes that start with 20 and 30, so any code such as 25.5, etc.

Comment: That predicate NSLogs to `code BEGINSWITH[cd] "18" AND code ENDSWITH[cd] "20"`, what i want is something like `code BETWEEN (code BEGINSWITH[cd] "18" AND code BEGINSWITH[cd] "20")` or something.

Comment: look you have a filter and then you want to filter with the results of that filter. So basically you'd have to run the first predicate (original question) twice to get your values (hopefully only two) other wise add some logic to pick two and then run your second predicate that you added to the question.